# is there any init entry point in google chrome extension that could set app config

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome v3 extension, now I read some config from local storage in pulic lib like this(this function may be used in different google chrome extension, different extension with different settings):

```
pluginLogin: async () => {
        let username:string = await LocalStorage.readLocalStorage(WheelGlobal.USER_NAME);
        let password:string = await LocalStorage.readLocalStorage(WheelGlobal.PASSWORD);
        let deviceId:string = await Device.getDeviceId();
        let appId:string = await LocalStorage.readLocalStorage(WheelGlobal.REDDWARF_APP_ID_KEY);
        let loginParams = {
            phone: username,
            password: password,
            deviceId: deviceId,
            app: Number(appId),
            deviceType: 7,
            loginType: LoginType.PHONE,
        };
        AuthHandler.login(loginParams);
    }
```

the function `pluginLogin` which invoke in the http interceptor when server side return not login response. and the login will trigger in background silently if user input the username and password for once.

what I want to do is store some system config like appId and other settings in the google chrome extension started or triggered for anyway(popup/script....). Is there have a startup point for me to put the setttings in one single places?

Now I can put the system setting in popup trigger or script trigger, but this way I must do the put system settting logic in different places. Is there one places to do this? or any other suggetsion?

Comment: Simply put it at the beginning of the script because the popup scripts run each time the popup opens, just like it happens in any other page you open.

Comment: background script or content script? @wOxxOm

Comment: Content scripts are also normal scripts that run each time the page opens. The background script script has its own lifetime but it also runs just like any normal script.

Comment: In other words all these scripts are separate, run just like any normal scripts do, and don't have any special entry point.